# Symmetric and antisymmetric powers of SU(2) representations

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, plethysm

Recently, I took a course in representation theory at Imperial College, and on the first homework the questions were about certain sneaky relationships when it came to representations of SU(2).

Denoting the $n/2$-representation of SU(2) by [$n$], we were asked to find the relationship between $\text{Sym}^{k} ([n])$ and $\text{Sym}^{n} ([k])$. In the previous questions we had proven among other things that $\text{Sym}^{2} ([n])=\text{Sym}^{n} ([2])$ and $\text{Sym}^{3} ([4])=\text{Sym}^{4} ([3])$. And so I figured, "Ah, they want us to show $\text{Sym}^{k} ([n]) = \text{Sym}^{n} ([k])$! Well, this should be easy!"

I thought it would take half an hour at most, that there was probably some combinatorial formula out there that allowed me to demonstrate it, but after five hours of work, I had to admit defeat. The next day, I admitted I had been defeated to the TA, and asked her to show me the actual proof of the matter, because I was now very interested in seeing it. She was a bit baffled that I had managed to spend 5 hours on the problem, and told me that all I was expected to do was to show that the *dimension* of $\text{Sym}^{k} ([n])$ equaled to the *dimension* of $\text{Sym}^{n} ([k])$ (which is rather trivial to prove, as the lectures had given us the derivation of the dimensionality formula of any symmetric power of SU(2)), and from that *infer* that $\text{Sym}^{k} ([n]) = \text{Sym}^{n} ([k])$.

This answer struck me as rather unsatisfying, and so I set out to try to find the formal proof. My searches on the internet yielded no result, and I cannot find it proven in any mathematics textbook. I am currently trying to go through ring theory and representation theory on my own, but I can see no end to my quest yet.

Consequently, I am now appealing to you ladies and gentlemen online for help on the matter, as the more I learn, the more difficult does it seem to me to prove that

$\text{Sym}^{k} ([n]) = \text{Sym}^{n} ([k])$.

Comment: This is a fine question to ask, but not here. If you ask it on http://math.stackexchange.com/ (or it gets migrated) I would be happy to answer it there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because Qiaochu promises to answer it elsewhere :)

Comment: Ah! I thought this was the Mathematics version of Physics StackExchange! (was a little curious about why it was called overflow and not StackExchange, though...) Sorry, my fault! How do It migrate it elsewhere?

Nevermind, just posted the question in the same format over there. Feel free to delete this whole thing here. Thanks for the quick reply and the promise of answering! :)

Comment: I don't really understand why the question was closed instead of migrated.

Comment: Since this did not get migrated and just for the record, the OP is asking about a proof of Hermite Reciprocity. The proof is in https://books.google.com/books?id=7R5bAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false starting from p. 172.